# Properties in my model are being duplicated for each item after adding to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a model and then adding that model to an array. However, once I add more than one item, some of the properties in my model ended up being duplicated.I have the following properties of type DrawnLayerModel:

```
model.overlay
model.fillcolor
model.linecolor
model.overlayString
```

OverlayString is the property that I'm most concerned with at the moment. Here is where I create the model object and add it to my array:

```
-(void)saveOverlay {
    DrawnLayerModel *model = [self.drawnLayerModel initWithOverlay:self.mapView.overlays.lastObject fillColor:self.customFillColor lineColor:self.customLineColor overlayTitle:self.layerName];
    [self.overlaysArray addObject:model];

    for (DrawnLayerModel *model in self.overlaysArray) {
        NSLog(@"Model ====> %@.", model);
        NSLog(@"Title ====> %@.", model.overlayTitle);
    }
}
```

Every time this button is pushed it adds a new model object:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UITextField *textfield = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
    self.layerName = textfield.text;
    [self.helpers createSuccessAlertContoller:self mapView:self.mapView title:@"Layer Successfully Saved!" message:@"Choose the layers button in the navigation bar to access saved layers."];
    [self saveOverlay];
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2018-02-05 13:47:12.387032-0800 prism[4910:1739598] Model ====> <DrawnLayerModel: 0x1c424d2c0>
2018-02-05 13:47:12.387166-0800 prism[4910:1739598] Title ====> Blue.
2018-02-05 13:47:12.387204-0800 prism[4910:1739598] Model ====> <DrawnLayerModel: 0x1c424d2c0>
2018-02-05 13:47:12.387235-0800 prism[4910:1739598] Title ====> Blue.
```

Now if you look at the DrawnLayerModel output these numbers are suspiciously the same:

```
0x1c424d2c0
```

Is that an address where the object was saved? Why are my properties being duplicated?

Comment: Please show the code that adds multiple objects to the array.

Comment: I saw some more of your code in your question a couple of days ago; I was concerned then about your use of a property for `drawnLayerModel` but presumed you had some reason for that. You really should alloc/init your object model when you need it rather than allocating one in a property and then initialising it later, since you can end up with the sort of issue you have here; one object being reused when you actually want multiple objects.

Comment: @Paulw11 Dude! You're right! Bingo!

Comment: @butter_baby that's exactly what my answer told you; I'll add that, but it's what I already said even without seeing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once I add multiple models to my array

The problem is with the code that does that:

```
DrawnLayerModel *model = [self.drawnLayerModel initWithOverlay:self.mapView.overlays.lastObject fillColor:self.customFillColor lineColor:self.customLineColor overlayTitle:self.layerName];
[self.overlaysArray addObject:model];
```

You are just reinitializing the same persistent object over and over (`self.drawnLayerModel`). Thus, you are adding the *same* object to the array *twice* (or more). Adding an object to an array doesn't copy it, and an object pointer is merely a reference, so you are able to add multiple references to one object to an array.

The *real* problem here is that you have broken the most basic law of instantiation in Objective-C: *Never say `init` without having said `alloc` in the very same set of square brackets*. And vice versa: *never say `alloc` without saying `init` in the same line*.

Comment: Sorry I just added the code that adds the multiple objects. It's grabs the string from a text field and stores it in self.layerName which then gets added to the model.